# Searching for two words in text in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, search, text

I have a table with tweet data in it. I can search for single words in the tweet data, but how do I effectively search for two words (whole table of them) in each sentence. I can most probably do a loop through all the words and search if it appears in the Twitter data, but is there a better way to search?

```
Twitter Data: "#Mdluli General Bheki Cele, Hawks head Anwa Dramat, operational services's Godfrey Lebeya and Gauteng's Mzwandile Petros were implicated."
```

Data I want returned:

```
Bheki Cele
Anwa Dramat
Mzwandile Petros
Godfrey Lebeya
```

Thanks

Andre

Comment: What is the structure of the table? What is your search query?

Comment: It's not too important but it is VARCHAR(250) for the Twitter data and VARCHAR(100) for the data to search for. What is important is, what is the easiest way to search for a table of 2 words in a given text string?